# How to rotate a log file in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: log, rsyslog

I am using metabase on a digital ocean droplet with ubuntu 18.04. I followed metabase [documentation](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-metabase-on-debian.html) for debian, but the problem is that after a while, I ended up with a `11GB` log file in `/var/logs/metabase.log`.

I cannot figure out how to rotate/limit the log file by size or something.

Frankly I don't really use the log at all but I would like it to be there just in case, but smaller.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Read `man logrotate`.

Comment: The link I gave is not relevant to my problem. I have a app that is creating a log file and I am asking how can I limit it's size.

Comment: is [this resource](https://www.tecmint.com/install-logrotate-to-manage-log-rotation-in-linux/) useful?